# read otp from SMS and set to edit text Not working

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, one-time-password

In my application, I am trying to read otp from SMS without typing inside my app. 
but it is not working I cant find out the error I am trying to correct the error more than a week please help me to find out where is the mistake, i create a class for reading incoming message and pass the value to my OTPActivity page but null value reaching there

IncomingSms.java

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;

                        String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().replaceAll("\\D", "");

                        //message = message.substring(0, message.length()-1);
                        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent("otp");
                        myIntent.putExtra("message", message);
                        myIntent.putExtra("number", senderNum);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(myIntent);
                        // Show Alert


                }

            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }
}
```

OTPActivity

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("otp"));
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("otp")) {
                final String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                // message is the fetching OTP
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                mPinEditText.setText(message);
 }
        }
    };

    //Initialization Varibles
    private void initViews() {
        if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(OTPActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(OTPActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, 100);
        } else {
            //Permission Granted
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Permission Granted
                } else {
                    //Permission Not Granted
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypkg.appanme">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Log shows this error

```
Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x19000010 (has extras) } to com.gameloft.android.HEP.GloftM5HP/.iab.SmsReceiver requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.phone (uid 1001)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"` to your receiver block in `AndroidManifest.xml` which is required to receive the SMS. Something like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".IncomingSms"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: i added these lines but it is not  wok

Comment: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x19000010 (has extras) } to com.gameloft.android.HEP.GloftM5HP/.iab.SmsReceiver requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.phone (uid 1001)  logcat shows

Comment: Where did you put permission? is it like this `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.package">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <application> ... </application>`?

Comment: yes after this  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypkg">

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write a receiver, you can use a simple lightweight library https://github.com/VitaliBov/SmsInterceptor

You only need to override the interface method, create an Interceptor class and bind it with the life cycle. It looks like this:

```
public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMessageListener {
    private SmsInterceptor smsInterceptor;
    private EditText etAuthPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);
        initViews();
        initSmsInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        smsInterceptor.register();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        smsInterceptor.unregister();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        smsInterceptor.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(String message) {
        // You can perform your validation here
        etAuthPassword.setText(message);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        etAuthPassword = findViewById(R.id.etAuthPassword);
        etAuthPassword.addTextChangedListener(new SmsTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.length() == 4) {
                    btnAuthPassword.setEnabled(true);
                    checkCode();
                } else {
                    btnAuthPassword.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initSmsInterceptor() {
        smsInterceptor = new SmsInterceptor(this, this);
        // Not necessary
        smsInterceptor.setRegex(SMS_CODE_REGEX);
        smsInterceptor.setPhoneNumber(PHONE_NUMBER);
    }

    private void checkCode() {
        // Validation
        if (isValid) {
            navigateToMainScreen();
        }
    }
}
```